# return from function (not working on a tutorial code)

Tags: python, function, return

Going on with the book How to Think Like a Computer Scientist. There is a piece of code that doesnt work - variable from inside the function doesnt get outside (NameError: name 'suma' is not defined). I suppose that the issue can be with the return statement, which on the other hand seems to be in accordance with tha manual.

It goes:

```
class Time:
    pass

time1=Time()    
time1.hours=11
time1.minutes=58
time1.seconds=30

time2=Time()    
time2.hours=11
time2.minutes=59
time2.seconds=30

def TimePrint(p):
    print(          int(p.hours), ":" , int(p.minutes) , ":" , int(p.seconds)               )
print()

# add these two times. Taken from the book, doesnt work though
def addTime(t1, t2):
    suma = Time()
    suma.hours = t1.hours + t2.hours
    suma.minutes = t1.minutes + t2.minutes
    suma.seconds = t1.seconds + t2.seconds

    if suma.seconds >= 60:
        suma.seconds = suma.seconds - 60
        suma.minutes = suma.minutes + 1
    if suma.minutes >= 60:
        suma.minutes = suma.minutes - 60
        suma.hours = suma.hours + 1
    return suma

TimePrint(suma)
```

May I ask for a help? Im 100% positive that the indents are in place.

Comment: TimePrint(addTime(time1, time2))

Comment: `suma` is defind locally in the scope of `addTime` and is not visible outside

Comment: WhatsThePoint: Yes, I also think so. But am not experienced enough to know the solution.

Comment: You should change TimePrint(suma) by TimePrint(addTime(time1, time2))

Comment: Oleksandr: Thanks! Thats it. Sorry for this indeed a beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what people said in comments is correct. I will explain a little.

`suma` is a local variable to `addTime()` and is not accessible outside the function.

Now you want to pass a `Time` class instance to `TimePrint()` function that is returned by `addTime()` function. As mentioned in comments, `TimePrint(addTime(time1, time2))` will do the trick.

To further simplify,

```
result = addTime(time1, time2)
TimePrint(result)
```